# Querying on Key-Value pair database in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table in MSSQL that is on metakey-value pair, what is the best function to use to select all distinct CustomerIDs if the meta values provided.

This is my current script.

```
DECLARE
    @name NVARCHAR(100) = 'Brian',
    @mobile NVARCHAR(100) = '0219002315'
SELECT cd.CustomerID FROM [dbo].[CustomerDetails] cd
 where (cd.MetaKey='First Name' AND cd.MetaValue=@name ) 
   or (cd.MetaKey='Mobile' AND cd.MetaValue=@mobile) 
group by cd.CustomerID
having count(*) = 2
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve is if I have value for @name, I will get those Customer whose metavalue = @name, if both @name and @mobile is given, I will only get those Customers who can satisfy both. My problem at the moment is, if @mobile or @name is null, I don't get any value.

My table is [dbo].[CustomerDetails]. With the following columns:
CustomerDetailsID
CustomerID
MetaKey
MetaValue

Answer (score 0):

You are having clause with COUNT(*) = 2. So, you are not getting any rows, if only one of them matches. You need to remove it.

```
DECLARE
    @name NVARCHAR(100) = 'Brian',
    @mobile NVARCHAR(100) = '0219002315'
SELECT cd.CustomerID FROM [dbo].[CustomerDetails] cd
 where (cd.MetaKey='First Name' AND cd.MetaValue=@name ) 
   or (cd.MetaKey='Mobile' AND cd.MetaValue=@mobile) 
group by cd.CustomerID
```

Comment: If I remove it, I would be getting all customers that have either 'first name' = brian or 'mobile' = '0219002315'; whereas I should only be getting one customer that satisfies both.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect more customers with a unique mobile number and first name?
If not, you can use following maybe

```
SELECT distinct cd.CustomerID 
FROM [dbo].[CustomerDetails] cd
where (cd.MetaKey='First Name' AND cd.MetaValue=@name ) 
   or (cd.MetaKey='Mobile' AND cd.MetaValue=@mobile)
```

Comment: I'll be expecting less customers if both variables have values. For example is I have 20 results with 'First Name' = Brian, and only one of them has 'Mobile' = '0219234778', so I should only get 1 result if both values are provided.

Comment: With this key pair you don't even need to use DISTINCT keyword.